# Variable definitions and C#

Tags: c#

I was wondering if somebody could explain how it is possible to assign a variable to another variable
even though that variable is not yet declared, as seen in the following code.

```
    public struct PointStruct
    {
        public int x;  //defining x var as publicly accessible
        public int y;  //defining Y var as publicly accessible

         public PointStruct(int x, int y)
         {
             this.x = x; //
             this.y = y; //
         }
    }
```

What is the point of "public PointStruct(int x, int y) if have already declared the variable,

is this section of code useless?

What is the technical name for this section of code?

Comment: I think you might need to do some minimal learning on C#

Comment: "Not yet declared" - they are. They aren't _initialised_ though.

Comment: the section of code is a constructor, and the constructor is taking parameters and assigning them to fields,  the field names and the parameter names are named the same, but are different.

Comment: public PointStruct(int x, int y) is your constructor so whenever you instantiate that struct outside of your struct you can assign variables outside of your struct to your struct's local variables.

Comment: @user3709460 you need to know about basics of programming for that vist [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms172579(v=vs.90).aspx) and then read about C# [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`public PointStruct(int x, int y)` is a constructor that is used to initialize the `public int x` and `public int y` properties in the `PointStruct` struct.

Even though the constructor parameters `int x` and `int y` have the same names as the public properties defined in the struct they are indeed different which is why you need to reference the public properties with `this.x` and `this.y`.

The scope of the variables passed to the constructor is only with the constructor itself. If you want to have access to the values passed into the constructor once it has finished running you need to assign it to variables that will be part of the object that is created.

Comment: "... that is used to initialize `x` and `y` in the PointStruct ***struct***."

Comment: @ScottChamberlain whoops! I missed that...and have now updated my answer. Thanks!